# Easiest way to deploy to tomcat for testing, which folder do I save my .war file to?

Tags: java, tomcat

I can deploy to tomcat currently by doing the following:

1. saving my .war file in the `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/` folder, and I delete the /ROOT folder.

I then modify the server.xml by adding this:

```
   <Context docBase="mywar.war" path="" />
```

But for some reason I keep getting caching issues when I stop tomcat, delete the .war file and the exploded folder, and then drop a new .war file in the webapps/ , it seems not use the updated codebase.

So I'm hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong or perhaps a better way to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason I keep getting caching issues when I stop tomcat, delete the .war file and the exploded folder, and then drop a new .war file in the webapps/ , it seems not use the updated codebase.

Also try clearing out the contents in tomcat/work directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploying using the tomcat user interface ?

follow the tutorial here : http://www.netadmintools.com/art340.html

the tutorial works for both windows and linux. If you are on windows restart the service to have the new user effective.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ant to build your war you can use the Tomcat-supplied library (catalina-ant.jar I believe) to deploy and undeploy your webapp from your build.xml.